# entity-framework error after update database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this error with entity freamwork

***"The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different context"***

it s happen after I

- add new fields in database 
  and update the model in entity entity-framework
- after i put the dal (project contain entity entity-framework)  in console project and rent this script

  ***Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges());***

to update the entity

but i have this error "The specified LINQ ..."

I checked in internet they said i have to update the .tt files or .edmx files
but didin t found any tt files or edmx file in my dal project

can you plz help me 
thank you

Comment: well without seeing your code it's a bit tricky to help, but it sounds like you combined queries from two different DbContexts, and possibly after you'd closed one of them. You can't do that. Use a single context. Pass it around as a variable if you need to.

Comment: Do you have an OnModelCreating method inside your DbContext file? If so, you'll have to add the entity to the model builder as well along with any constraints.

Comment: Do you have a `Seed` method? It's impossible to answer this without seeing class definitions and the code that actually throws the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found where are my error

the is tried to query two repository

didn't know each repository has his own db context
my error was that :

```
from football in  repoFootabll.Query().Where (x => x.id = 12)
From members in repoMember.Query().where(x=> x.FootaballId = football.id)
select (repo2)
```

To fix that i just add dbset of football  in  Member repository

```
class repoMember 
{
    dbSet<football> foot
    dbSet<member> memeber
 ...
}
```

and create the function inisde my repo member  :

thank s to  ***ADyson***  who help me for that

```
getmemebers()
{
     from football in  foot.Where (x => x.id = 12)
    From members in memeber.where(x=> x.FootaballId = football.id)
    select (members)
}
```